# Rails: Javascript dropdown not loading when clicked on. Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

when i clicked on my javascript dropdown, the dropdown couldn't load. I am using Rails 5.1.2, Ruby, 2.4.1, and the gem 'jquery-rails'

HTML in _header.html.erb

```
<li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
          Account <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Settings", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Change Password?", new_password_reset_path %></li>
```

Application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Do you get any error in console ?

Answer (score 0):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined.

*Jquery* need to be the **first script** when you import. Try changing the content of `application.js` to below

```
#application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails-ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree
```

Notice that the order has been changed.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Still cannot work. I have this in the Javascript Console: application-10d7da6ddae5fbd3169dcdb87ee6e397814e304ae1e30af1526567d8549d7e72.js:1323 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at application-10d7da6ddae5fbd3169dcdb87ee6e397814e304ae1e30af1526567d8549d7e72.js:1323
    at application-10d7da6ddae5fbd3169dcdb87ee6e397814e304ae1e30af1526567d8549d7e72.js:1355

Comment: @Divine Where do you have the scripts? in `app/assets/javascripts`?

Comment: I have it at application.js